# How to determine the child of an inheritance in Power Designer

Tags: c#, powerdesigner

I have an entity object in Power Designer and walk through its inheritances but I do not know how to get the child object. Could someone post an example code? It is also important to get the Object ID of the inheritance.

Edit: solution Idea based on pascals examples:

```
foreach (PdCDM.Inheritance curPDInheritance in curPDEntity.InheritedBy){
  foreach(PdCDM.InheritanceLink curPDInheritanceLink in curPDInheritance.InheritanceLinks){
    Console.WriteLine(curPDEntity.Name + " parent of " + ((PdCDM.Entity)curPDInheritanceLink.ChildEntity).Name+ " through " + curPDInheritance.Name + " (" + curPDInheritance.ObjectID + ")");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples in VBScript. It will give you an idea of the collections you're looking for. The first one directly gives the entities inheriting from the an entity.

```
option explicit
dim mdl : set mdl = ActiveModel
dim ent,chl
for each ent in mdl.Entities
   for each chl in ent.InheritedByEntities
      output ent.Name + " parent of " + chl.Name
   next
next
```

The second example enumerates the inheritances, to retrieve their child entities:

```
option explicit
dim mdl : set mdl = ActiveModel
dim ent,inh,chl
for each ent in mdl.Entities
   for each inh in ent.InheritedBy
      for each chl in inh.ChildEntities
         output ent.Name + " parent of " + chl.Name + " through " + inh.Name + " (" + inh.ObjectID + ")"
      next
   next
next
```

EDIT: if your version of PowerDesigner does not have `.ChildEntities`, you can try through the InheritanceLink which links the child entity, with the inheritance:

```
option explicit
dim mdl : set mdl = ActiveModel
dim ent,inh,ilk
for each ent in mdl.Entities
   for each inh in ent.InheritedBy
      for each ilk in inh.InheritanceLinks
         output ent.Name + " parent of " + ilk.Object2.Name + " through " + inh.Name + " (" + inh.ObjectID + ")"
      next
   next
next
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples! I have a question: The 3rd loop in the second example returns for every child the same inheritance id. Is this correct?

Comment: The C# object PdCDM.Inheritance have not a attribute called ChildEntities - only ChildrenList and this is a string instead of a collection.

Comment: I ran my example with 16.5 SP03. I've added another example, using the InheritanceLink.

Comment: The 3rd example brings me nearer, thanks! But how I can get the ObjectId of ilk.Object2?

Comment: ((PdCDM.Entity)curPDInheritanceLink.ChildEntity) is the key! Thank you! :)